# PHP preg_replace oddity with £ pound sign and ã

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am applying the following function

```
<?php

function replaceChar($string){
    $new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\sçéèêëñòóôõöàáâäåìíîïùúûüýÿ]/", "", $string);
    return $new_string;
}

$string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£%^#&$ and foreign letters éèêëñòóôõöàáâäåìíîïùúûüýÿ";

echo replaceChar($string);
?>
```

which works fine but if I add ã to the preg_replace like

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\sçéèêëñòóôõöàáâãäåìíîïùúûüýÿ]/", "", $string);

$string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£%^#&$ and foreign letters éèêëñòóôõöàáâäåìíîïùúûüýÿã";
```

It conflicts with the pound sign £ and replaces the pound sign with the unidentified  question mark in black square.

This is not critical but does anyone know why this is?

Thank you,

Barry

UPDATE: Thank you all. Changed functions adding the u modifier: pt2.php.net/manual/en/… – as suggested by Artefacto and works a treat

```
function replaceChar($string){
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\sçéèêëñòóôõøöàáâãäåìíîïùúûüýÿ]/u", "", $string);
return $new_string;
}
```

Comment: What character encoding do you use?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your string is in UTF-8, you must add the `u` modifier to the regex. Like this:

```
function replaceChar($string){
    $new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\sçéèêëñòóôõöàáâäåìíîïùúûüýÿ]/u", "", $string);
    return $new_string;
}

$string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£%^#&$ and foreign letters éèêëñòóôõöàáâäåìíîïùúûüýÿ";

echo replaceChar($string);
```

Comment: i just want to replace £ pound but your above function replaceChar, it replace also % and other sign, so i can make it only to replace pound sign ?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that your string is UTF-8, but preg_replace() is working on bytes

Answer (score 0):

that code is valid ...

maybe you should try Central-European character encoding

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [mb_ereg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php). As Mark mentioned preg_replace only works on byte level and does not work well with multibyte character encodings.

Cheers,
Fabian

Comment: Not entirely true. preg_replace can work with UTF-8 strings. Se here the u modifier: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: I've tried 
I've tried 
$new_string = mb_ereg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\sçéèêëñòóôõöàáâãäåìíîïùúûüýÿ]/", "", $string);
but this doesn't remove the symbols !£%^#&$

Comment: Thank you guys 
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\sçéèêëñòóôõöàáâãäåìíîïùúûüýÿ]/u", "", $string);

Works a treat